# jQuery does not work in IE but works with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have a sample html code here and javascript that is perfectly working fine when being browsed by Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, but when viewed from Internet Explorer 9, it is now messing up.

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dummy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dummy" style="display:none;"><option value="dummy">dummy</option></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <tbody id="MultCompanyIdPane">  </tbody>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script>modifyMultCompIdFunc();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my sample javascript is:

```
function modifyMultCompIdFunc() {
    $("#MultCompanyIdPane").show();

        var html =
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td align="left">Company:</td>' +
                    '<td align="right">' + 
                        '<select id="var" class="UserMgmtInputText">' +
                            $("div#dummy").html() +
                        '</select>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        $("#MultCompanyIdPane").append(html);
}
```

I've already tried to reset my IE configurations but it doesn't solve the issue.  Any ideas on how to solve this issue?  Or am I doing it wrong?

It mess up in terms of display, when being viewed in google chrome/mozilla, the drop-down list box is working (there's a value on the select box), but when viewed using IE9, there's no value in the drop-down list box.

Thanks.

Comment: and what is the result in the web inspector? (F12) Can you see the <option> appearing?

Comment: I don't know if `<option value>dummy</option>` is valid markup. I don't know either how IE treats invalid markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your example.

1. MultCompanyIdPane id is used 2 times.
2. IE not allow `<option>` tag to be used otside of `<select>` tag. That's why `$("div#dummy").html()` returns just text `dummy` instead of `<option value="dummy">dummy</option>`.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eGEBJ/2/).

Comment: Follow up question, if that's the case then is it possible for me to generate a "multiple items" on my select tag on a single div using this approach?

Comment: Yes. For example put multiple `<p>` in that div ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGEBJ/5/)). But actually there is a lot more possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `<tbody>` elements with the same id (MultCompanyIdPane). Also, your `<option>` tag should be either `<option>dummy</option>` or `<option value="dummy">dummy</option>`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.  But I already modified the code (I have updated the question) and still getting the same result.